# Grails variable request has "+" between words instead of spaces

Tags: javascript, grails

I have the following:

```
<g:each status="i" var="grade" in="${chooseList}">
    <div id="grade_${grade}" class="dojoDndItem" dndType="avail">
        <g:remoteLink action="getMappings" controller="dataManagement" update="mappedSkills" params="[grade:grade.toString()]" id="1">${grade}</g:remoteLink>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

When I print out params.grade in my controller, it "looks+like+this"

in other words, the spaces are replaced with "+"

what causes that? Can I get rid of it, or do I have to take care of it from within my controller?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your values are coming in from params as URL Encoded.  Try `params.grade.decodeURL()` in your controller to remove the pluses.